# Fourier transform real and imaginary part question?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have to find the fourier transform of $f(t)=e^{-a^*t}*u(t)$

For a>0 the signal has an infinite value therefore doesnt have a Fourier transform.For a>0 we have:

$F(w)=\int_0^∞[e^{-a*t}*e^{-j*w*t}]\,dt$ = $\int_0^∞e^{{[-a+jw}]*t}\,dt$=

$[1/-(a+jw)]$*$[e^{-(a+jw)*t}]|_0^∞$

From here,in my book it says $F(w)=1/(a+jw)$=$[a/(a^2+w^2)$-$j*a/(a^2+w^2)]$

But can you please do this integral $[1/-(a+jw)]$*$[e^{-(a+jw)*t}]|_0^∞$ to me step by step?

Also,how did we find the real and the imaginary parts ?

Real part : $[a/(a^2+w^2)]$

Imaginary part:$[j*a/(a^2+w^2)]$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a > 0$ and $g$ be the function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by :

$$\forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \; g(t)=
\begin{cases}
e^{-at} & \text{if } t \geq 0 \\[2mm]
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

$g$ is in $\mathrm{L}^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and its Fourier transform at some point $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ is given by :

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}(g)(\omega) & = {} \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(t) e^{-it\omega} \; dt \\[2mm]
 & = \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-at} e^{-it\omega} \; dt \\[2mm]
 & = \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-(a+i\omega)t} \; dt \\[2mm]
 & = \lim \limits_{M \to +\infty} \Big[ -\frac{1}{a+i\omega} e^{-(a+i\omega)t} \Big]_{0}^{M} \\[2mm]
 & = \frac{1}{a+i\omega}.
\end{align*}
$$

Remember that for any complex number $z$, $\overline{z} z = \vert z \vert^{2}$. So, $\mathcal{F}(g)(\omega)$ writes :

$$ \mathcal{F}(g)(\omega) = \frac{a-i\omega}{\vert a+i\omega \vert^{2}} = \frac{a-i\omega}{a^{2}+\omega^{2}} $$

As a consequence,

$$ \Re \Big( \mathcal{F}(g)(\omega) \Big) = \frac{a}{a^{2}+\omega^{2}} \quad \mathrm{and} \quad \Im \Big( \mathcal{F}(g)(\omega) \Big) = -\frac{\omega}{a^{2}+\omega^{2}}$$

where $\Re(z)$ (resp. $\Im(z)$) is the real (resp. imaginary) part of $z$. I think that answers your question. Now, if $f$ is given by :

$$ f = g \star u $$

where $\star$ is the convolution between $g$ and some integrable function $u$, you will have :

$$ \mathcal{F}(f)(\omega) = \mathcal{F}(g)(\omega) \times \mathcal{F}(u)(\omega) = \frac{\mathcal{F}(u)(\omega)}{a+i\omega} $$